# Switch monitors on ThinkPad W520 while docked

Tags: arch-linux, xrandr, laptop, multi-monitor

I'm trying to make my (ThinkPad W520) laptop monitor turn on (by itself, with the other monitors turning off) using xrandr when docked and connected to external monitors. My end goal is to automatically reconfigure between docking and undocking and to let me switch one of the displayed monitors to a TV (HDMI) and back, but I'm trying to start small. I've read on some forums that I need to turn off the external monitors first before I can bring up the internal one, but I haven't had any luck.  I'm using the Nouveau driver on Arch Linux. Below is what I have so far. However, executing this leaves me with no monitors and I have to restart.

```
xrandr --output DP-2 --off
xrandr --output DP-3 --off
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --primary
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried turning LVDS-1 *on* (with `--auto`) before turning the other screens off?